# LFSR description right?

Tags: system-verilog

I wrote a 32-bit LFSR based on the taps from [1]. I want to ask if the following description is right for the 32-bit LFSR with the taps 32,22,2 and 1.

```
module lfsr (
  input  logic        clk_i,
  input  logic        rst_i,
  output logic [31:0] rand_o
);

  logic[31:0] lfsr_value;

  assign rand_o = lfsr_value;

  always_ff @(posedge clk_i, negedge rst_i) begin
    if(~rst_i) begin
      lfsr_value <= '0;
    end else begin
      lfsr_value[31:1] <= lfsr_value[30:0];
      lfsr_value[0]    <= ~(lfsr_value[31] ^ lfsr_value[21] ^ lfsr_value[1] ^ lfsr_value[0]);
    end
  end
endmodule
```

[1] http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf

Comment: Looks Correct to create 1 bit of randomness per clk.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Ok. you could also use an XOR, instead of an XNOR, as long as you reset to something else (the XOR version locks up at all 0's, the XNOR at all 1's).

For many apps the pseudo-random output is the single bit you shift out (31 in your case), rather than the entire register. It's also (more?) common to shift right, and put the XOR data in the top bit, and use the bit 0 output as your PR data.

Your code is specifically SystemVerilog, and not Verilog, so I've removed the Verilog tag.